# "Unhide" text using only CSS

Tags: html, css, hide

I'm trying to change what text is shown based on screen width.

Default is `#name` (with `#name2` hidden), and when the screen is under a certain width, that becomes hidden and `#name2` is revealed.

This works perfectly on my local WAMP server, but does not work on the web server.

Is it possible for this to work without using js?

If I don't begin with `#name2` as `display:none`, they both will display on top of each other.

In the current version, if I shrink the screen, `#name` will disappear, but `#name2` does not appear on the web version (only on the local version).

Using php if that matters.

Thank you!

HTML

```
<a href="index.php" id="name">Full Name</a>
<a href="index.php" id="name2">Initials</a>
```

CSS

```
#name {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: "Garamond";
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 5px;
  left: 30px;
  color: white;
}

#name2 {
  display: none;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: "Garamond";
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 5px;
  left: 30px;
  color: white;
}


@media (max-width: 1000px){
  #name {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1000px){
  #name2 {
      display: inline;
  }
}
```

Comment: Interesting - I made this change last night and couldn't get it to work. I reloaded page this morning and it worked fine. Any idea why this specific change would have required longer for the server to implement? Tested on multiple devices last night and it wasn't working, now suddenly it is.

Comment: First of using php cant help on this matter. Second if you want something to happen based on user interactions that means javascript.

Comment: @user3506835 You don't need two `@media` queries since both of the parameters are the same. You can put them in the same one

Comment: Are you sure you've included/uploaded all javascript files such as jQuery to your production version?

Comment: Are you sure there are no overriding styles/stylesheet present on the live version? Have you tried clearing your browser cache?

Comment: thanks everyone - seems to be working fine now. And yes good call Zach on combining the queries